# Woocommerce Product Gallery Slider not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am using a plugin (Advanced Woocommerce Product Gallery Slider ) to create a sliding gallery of images on my product page - however the spacings between the thumbnails is too large, and the main image has a wide space before the scrolling arrow

[Link to website in question](https://poshreffcosmetics.co.za/product/liquid-matte-lipsticks/)

I have tried adjusting the size of the single product image of WooCommerce, as well as the width of the gallery in the plugin gallery settings but cannot fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

padding between the thumbnails origin is:

```
ul.products li.product {
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

padding at the top of the content origin is:

```
.page_content:not(:empty), .tribe-events-pg-template {
    padding: 76px 0;
}
```

It looks like you will have to do a woocommerce override for the first css. and The second is in a layout.css file to edit.